# Fast method for testing a bit of a large int

Tags: python, python-3.x, optimization, micro-optimization, largenumber

In a number-theoretic algorithm manipulating very large integer `n` (hundred thousand bits to few millions), I need to test the `j`<sup>th</sup> bit. Either of these work:

```
if 1<<j & n != 0 :
    # bit j of n is set

if n>>j & 1 != 0 :
    # bit j of n is set
```

but the duration of the test grows linearly with `n.bit_length()` (for `j` half that). Otherwise said per [big-O notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation), time is O(log(`n`)), when that could be O(1).

Is there an O(1) idiom to test a bit of an `int` in Python 3(.8), like we have `mpz_tstbit()` in GMP?

If not, where is the drop box for Python suggestions?

---

Addition per [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/103636029): `n.bit_length()` is at most `1<<24`, with `j < n.bit_length()` and `j>=0`.

Comment: This kind of bit-twiddling is usually done to save memory. Do you have *lots* of such integers? A simple list of Booleans might be more useful: `if n[j]: ...`.

Comment: That said, you should profile the code before worrying whether your current approach is fast enough.

Comment: @chepner: here, I aso perform arithmetic with this integer `n`, thus an array of booleans or bytes won't cut it. I know the rule to optimize after benchmarking; but if the idiom that I ask exists, it will also make the intent clearer..

Comment: well on the subject of micro-optimizations, can't `if 1<<j & n != 0:` just be `if  1<<j & n:`?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: indeed. But that's a micro saving, of order O(1), when I'm after a gain of O(Log(`n`)).

Comment: A C function that knows the internal layout of Python integers could almost certainly do this test faster, but I doubt such a function already exists.

Comment: Do you have or can set an upper bound for `j`?

Comment: If you want functionality like this, you should probably just *use* GMP. [There are Python bindings for that.](https://pypi.org/project/gmpy2/)

Comment: GMP should speed up most large int operations, not just this one. Python's `int` implementation prioritizes simplicity over power or speed.

Comment: Python stores large integers internally in "chunks" of 30 bits (in a 32-bit integer), so it can emulate carry propagation by doing math that won't overflow.  IDK if there's a way to index a chunk in Python.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Disclaimer: I maintain `gmpy2`.*

`gmpy2` supports bit access in a few different ways. The `gmpy2.bit_test(n,j)` will test the j-th bit of n. `n` can be either a Python integer or a `gmpy2` integer type.

```
>>> gmpy2.bit_test(78,2)
True
```

The `gmpy2.mpz` integer type support a `bit_test` method. Other methods are also supported.

```
>>> a=gmpy2.mpz(123456)
>>> a.bit_test(27)
False
```

`gmpy2.xmpz` is a mutable integer type that supports bit access, including setting bits and accessing slices of bits.

```
>>> a=gmpy2.xmpz(123456)
>>> a[27]
0
>>> a[27]=1
>>> a[27]
1
>>> a[27:30]
mpz(1)
>>> a[27:30] = -1
>>> a[27:30]
mpz(7)
```

You can use `xmpz` integers in normal math operations. If you only use immediate operations (+=, *=, etc.), then the `xmpz` object will be updated in-place.

```
>>> a
xmpz(939647552)
>>> b=a
>>> a+=9999
>>> a
xmpz(939657551)
>>> b
xmpz(939657551)
```

`xmpz` integers are a little strange at times, but they usually are very fast for direct bit access.

Comment: `pip3 install https://download.lfd.uci.edu/pythonlibs/g5apjq5m/gmpy2-2.0.8-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl` and I have gmp with convenient wrapper classes in Python 3.8!! For other versions of Python use the appropriate whl at [Christoph Gohlke's repository](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#gmpy). Giving the path to a previously downloaded file also works.

Answer (score 2):

If your "j" is fixed you can spell the number in literal form instead of using "j" - Python's compiler then would record "1 << j" as a literal, and  you d have a single operation instead of two.(That is, if "j" is not variable, and is always, say "10204", you should write `1 << 10204`)

That said, I think you are imagining this algorithm run as "calmly pushing the 1 thousands of bits to the left, one by one" - that is not what happens.

The algorithm for big integers will likely optimze a lot the creation of the "1 << j" integer - and while the result of that `& n` will be "linear" it will still be a very fast operation.

All in all, if after you are running and a profile of your app shows you there is a slow down in this operation, there are big-integer libraries that can outperform Python's native integers by more than one order of magnitude.

In the past I've used the GMP2 libray - available to Python as [gmpy2](https://pypi.org/project/gmpy2/2.1.0a2/) and got good results.\

As for the specifics of your question, about trying to speed things up by writing other expressions for the bit testing: that is definetelly the wrong approach -

If it would be the case for the numbers in Python been *too* slow, and the faster numeric libraries not supporting the bit-testing at all, you culd roll out your own integer types, that would store the bug numbers in a bytearray, with 8 bits per byte, and write a custom "bit compare" method for these numbers.

The speedup you would gain relative to testing with normal bitwise `&` is that your function would know in advance it has to match a single bit on one of the operands, and don't have to search for other "1" bits in the other operand - so the operation would be O(1).

But I'd bet the speedup you'd get from this would be too little - keep in mind that "premature optimization is the root of all evil".

**update**: gmp is not faster for building the 1 << j number:

```
In [22]: a = bmpy2.numer(1); b = gmpy2.numer(10_000_000)                                                                                                   

In [23]: %timeit a << b                                                                                                                
25.8 µs ± 508 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

In [24]: %timeit 1 << 10_000_000                                                                                                       
27.2 µs ± 239 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

Comment: No, I'm not imagining that it pushes the 1 to the left j times, which would have cost O(`j`^2), thus ultimately O(Log(`n`)^2). I'm imagining (and pretty confident) that the cost is O(Log(`n`)), when it could be O(1). gmpy2 might be a good idea, but it's not exactly a Python idiom.

Comment: (answer apart, Im amde some "timeit"s with `2 ** j` instead of `1 << j`  -and it is a full 1000 times slower. There is definetelly space in Python's compile/parse time optimizations for making that better.

Comment: Even if some static type analysis allows to determine that `j` is going to be an integer, we need to know that `j`is non-negative to replace `2**j` with `1<<j`, and that's not easy (Python does not even have unsigned int). That probably has to do with why `2**j` is slower.

Comment: I conclude there is no built-in idiom (except perhaps indexing the internal representation of `int` as [hinted](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/103641762), at the expense of clarity and compatibility with possible evolutions). I accept the wisdom (seconded in [two](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/103641537) [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/103641611)) that if performance is utmost, GMP bindings is the way to go. It would indeed speed-up other parts of the algorithm. Too bad to have to choose between speed and simplicity+clarity.

Comment: You did not say much of your other constraints - but a relatively easy thing would be subclassing "int", and on its `__new__` return store its plain byte-representation in an attribute - (`int.to_bytes` method), and have a method to check for a single set bit that would be O(1) by looking on this byte-array.

There are obvious overheads in space and processing, but they are paid a single time for each big integer.